# ruby: error running action after user update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm uploading a file that is saved on the user DB with carrierwave. After updating with the file, I want to call an action that copy that file to other location. My problem is that when I call that action it gives me this erro `(Errno::EISDIR - Is a directory @ rb_sysopen)` , because it doesn't recognize the file created, but if I refresh the file is in the DB (and if I call copy_file action on other location rather then in update it works well, but I want to copy the file only when the user uploads).

This are my two actions, **update**, and after running the update calls **copy_file**:

```
  def copy_file

    require "fileutils"
    my_dir = Dir['./public/'+current_user.personal_file_url.to_s]
    my_dir.each do |filename|
      # name = File.basename('data', '.xml')[0,4]
      dest_folder = "./public/files/"


      FileUtils.cp(filename, dest_folder + "data.xml")
     # File.rename(filename, dest_folder + "/" + "data" + File.extname(filename))


    end

    bat_file

    #redirect_to personal_performance_path

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json


  def update  #upload personal file



    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'File was sucessfully uploaded!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }

      #  copy_file  #make a copy of the uploaded file in public/files/data.xml for running in the bat file
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end

 copy_file

  end
```

Comment: Why don't you copy over to a `tempfile`, and copy the Tempfile to whatever file you want to, then `.unlink` the temp file to delete it. This will save on performance, and will also get rid of your error. That error means the file isn't a file, it's a directory. For whatever reason Ruby is reading your file as a directory and won't copy it. Try the `tempfile` solution and see how that works. Also `FileUtils.cp` doesn't really do anything read the docs http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html

Comment: but this action is working if I call it from other place after the user is updated

Comment: how can I do that tempfile method?

Answer (score 0):

`TempFile` method:

You can do this a few ways, I preferably create a module for it, you can do it however you want to:

```
require 'tempfile'

module Temp

  def copy_file(file1, file2)
    file = TempFile.new(file1) #<= name your temp file
    # the easiest way to do this is just to open the files and append to them
    File.open(file2).each_line do |s|
      File.open(file) { |tmp| tmp.puts(s) }
      # you can choose to either truncate file2 or delete depending on what you need to do, you could also give it another argument in order to write to another file etc..
    end
   file.unlink #<= delete the tempfile
  end
end

Temp.copy_file('test', 'example.txt')
```

That's a basic understanding of using a temporary file

Here's an example of a Copy module, you can easily integrate a tempfile into [this](https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow/blob/master/lib/copy.rb).

Comment: i dont know why im getting `uninitialized constant UsersController::TempFile` , I have require 'tempfile'

Comment: After some research I found this: https://hackhands.com/rails-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-class-solution/

Comment: Let me do some research on lunch and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm on lunch, so are you by chance using heroku?

Comment: Or possibly check is your `UsersController` is named `UserController`

Comment: im not using heroku and it is UsersController